# Google translate text-to-speech in British

Tags: google-translate, text-to-speech

I'm using the (unofficial) Google translate TTS api to retrieve mp3s to support disabled learners to read web pages. It all works fine, however we have an American accent (we're in the UK!). When I use Google translate however, it fetches the mp3 with a British accent - how do I invoke this behavior?

I've used the same GET request URL so I can assume it's not that:

```
http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?q=testing+1+2+3&tl=en
```

(I've played with other language codes (en-gb) with no luck - fr works for french however.)

Many thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By using google's ".co.uk" translate site's GET request, you can generate British English.
So for example: translate.google.co.uk/translate_tts?q=Your+soundcard+works+perfectly&tl=en

Comment: Works most of the time, but not always. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/13996110/78234

Answer (score 15):

You can specify a regional variation in the tl parameter after an `_` character, e.g.

http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?q=testing+1+2+3&tl=en_us

http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?q=testing+1+2+3&tl=en_gb

http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?q=testing+1+2+3&tl=en_au

Comment: A weird side-effect using this approach with 'en_au', it reads a comma as pronounced 'comma'.